# Identifying polygons within shapefile which are arranged in line from polygons in scattered

Tags: qgis

I have a shapefile in QGIS comprised of lots of polygons. I am trying to separate the polygons which are shaped in lines (like those within the red box) from those polygons which are more scattered/random (within the blue box). I can't seem to find a tool which seems to do this, and beginning to wonder whether this is even possible.

[image]

Comment: If you wish to also ask about ArcMap, R or Python please do so in separate questions. For R and Python please include a code snippet that illustrates what you’ve tried and where you’re stuck.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an idea that will require some tweaking:

1. Buffer the polygons with a distance just enough to make the line polygons touch
2. Dissolve the boundaries
3. Multipart to singlepart
4. Oriented minimum bounding box. The polygons on a line will get enclosed in long and thin boxes, and the rest will have more square boxes.
5. Extract the long and thin boxes by their roundness.
   `($area*4*pi()/$perimeter^2)<0.5`. I use 0.5, adjust it

As you can see, long thin polygons have a lower value:
[image]

You can then use the resulting polygons to Select/Extract by location

[image]